# rails 2.3 button_to, forms and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to create a button in one class that sends the user to a form to create another class. This is the most simple has_many/belong_to relationship but Im rather confused.

Two classes: Events and Impacts. Events has_many Impacts.

creating a link from Events::Show to Impacts::New was trivial:

```
<%= link_to "Add impact", new_impact_path(event_id: @event.id) %>
```

generates:

```
<a href="/impacts/new?event_id=5">Add impact</a>
```

this sends a request to the impacts controller and calls the new() method with params[:event_id] = 5

however I havent been able to understand how to do this with button_to

**method #1** 
Without changing any routes, I thought this was correct. It calls Impacts::New with with params[:event_id].

```
<%= button_to "New -loses ID", options = {:controller => "impacts", :action => "new", :event_id => @event.id }, html_options={:method => "get" }   %>
```

generates

```
<form action="/impacts/new?event_id=5" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input type="submit" value="New -loses ID"></div></form>
```

routes.rb shows:

```
new_impact GET    /impacts/new(.:format)      impacts#new
```

However when Impacts::New executes, there is no parameter passed. It calls the right method but the param gets striped out somehow (and I cannot tell why/where).

**method #2** 
when I changed my routes.rb:

```
resources :events do 
   resources :impacts 
end
```

routes.rb now shows:

```
new_event_impact GET    /events/:event_id/impacts/new(.:format)      impacts#new
```

the generated code is completely different but it works.

```
<form action="/events/5/impacts/new" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input type="submit" value="New -loses ID"></div></form>
```

so my questions:

Why does method #1 lose the parameter?

Why does method #2 work?

I suspect the answer is that I don’t understand routes :)

thanks